# 英語が残っている: untagged タグをつけようとした時のメッセージ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> This is a special tag that is designed to be used only by the system for questions that have had all of their other tags removed. Please use a real tag instead.

Transifex にも登録されていないようです(e.g. [`TEXT: special tag`](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english?q=special%20tag))。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> このタグはシステムですべてのタグを取り外した場合のみの特別タグです。[他のタグ]を利用してください。

がサイトに反映されています。